# program Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I installed Android Studio version 3.2.1 on Windows 10. My Gradle doesn't build after trying for around 2 days. I have a problem that I don't understand. When I run the program, execution fails for task `:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`. What can I do?

[image: error]

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

try command "gradlew assembleDebug -is" in your IDE terminal, it will tell you where your code error occurred. BTW, javac task error means your code cannot pass java compiler ,and your picture showed the errors , such as " cannot find symbol class R..."